# How can I print "-n" with `echo`?

Tags: echo, arguments

I can't figure how to print the string "-n" with the over 30 years-old command `echo`.

I tried these:

```
Michaels:Scripts$ echo -n
Michaels:Scripts$ echo "-n"
Michaels:Scripts$ echo -e "-n"
Michaels:Scripts$ echo -- -n
-- -n
Michaels:Script$ echo -- "-n"
-- -n
Michaels:Script$ echo "\-n"
\-n
```

I use Mac OS X ML. I consider this behaviour very weird and unexpected.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258664/echo-n-will-not-print-n

Comment: There is a possibility where you could use a space e.g `echo " -n"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to use `prinf` you have a couple of of options, at least according to this SO Q&A, titled: [echo “-n” will not print -n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258664/echo-n-will-not-print-n).

This seems to be your best option:

```
$ echo "x-n" | cut -c 2-
-n
```

Or some variation:

```
$ echo -- '-n'|cut -d" " -f2
-n
```

#### printf

`printf` doesn't have this issue:

```
$ printf "%s\n" -n
-n
```

Comment: Could you please explain the second command, esp. the cut-part of it :)

Comment: @Michael - sure, it takes the output from `echo -- '-n'`, which is `-- -n`. `cut` then splits the output on spaces, and takes the 2nd field, hence the `-n`.

Answer (score 10):

Why would you want to use `echo`? [Use `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22565):

```
printf -- '-n\n'
```

Or:

```
printf '%s\n' -n
```

With `echo`:

```
echo -n
```

Will output `-n<LF>` in a UNIX conformant `echo`.

`bash`, `dash`, GNU or `zsh` echo (in their default configurations on most systems) can do it with:

```
echo -en '-n\n'
```

Or (on ASCII-based systems):

```
echo -e '\055n'
```

Zsh `echo` can do it with:

```
echo - -n
```

Or (assuming the `bsdecho` option is not enabled):

```
echo '\u002Dn'
```

Fish's `echo` with:

```
echo -- -n
```

Ksh and Zsh's `print` can do it with:

```
print - -n
```

or:

```
print -- -n
```

`bash` (but not `zsh`), assuming the `posix` and `xpg_echo` are not both enabled:

```
echo -n -; echo n
```

Interestingly, it is impossible to output `-n` with `echo` alone in a POSIX way (that is, more or less, portably across Unices and Unix-likes), since the behaviour if the first argument is `-n` or if any argument contains backslash characters is unspecified.

Comment: If you have a unicode terminal, you could output \u2011 (or \u2010) which look identical to a -. But that's hardly a solution (and there's no portable way to introduce the unicode characters without knowing the encoding of the terminal emulator).

Comment: I am using ksh, echo -e "\x2d" is printing "\x2d" but octal expression echo -e "\055" is printing the correct "-" . Any thoughts please? Thanks

Comment: @CppLearner, yes `echo` is not portable. Don't use `echo`. For Unix compliant `echo`'s `echo '\055'` would output the 0x2d byte (`-` in ASCII, but Unix systems are not required to use ASCII as their base charsets, some still use EBCDIC). But the behaviour for `echo '\x2d'` is unspecified. Similarly `printf '\055'` is POSIX and portable, `printf '\x2d'` is neither.

Comment: Thank you so much Stéphane Chazelas for clarification and quick turnaround.

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons, `echo` doesn't do the usual kind of argument parsing where any argument that starts with `-` is an option except that `--` signals the end of option. The `echo` command mostly prints its arguments unchanged, but depending on the unix variant, on the shell and on how the shell is configured, it may interpret some options (`-e`, `-E`, `-n`, `-`) and may treat backslash+character specially.

There's no portable way to print `-n` with `echo` alone. The portable way to print a string without having to worry about special characters is

```
printf %s -n
```

or more generally `print %s "$somestring"`. If you want to print a final newline after the string, make that `printf '%s\n' -n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you need "-n" as a first two symbols:

```
echo -e '\r-n'
```

Another one way:

```
echo -n '-'; echo 'n'
```

Comment: This prints an extra CR at the beginning.

Comment: What kind of term do you use?

Comment: What kind of what? Shell? Any shell that implements `-e` will print 4 bytes: `0d 2d 6e 0a` (written out in hex). Any shell that doesn't implement `-e` will print either `2d 65 20 5c 72 2d 6e 0a` or `2d 65 20 0d 2d 6e 0a`.

Comment: Or did you mean what kind of terminal? That's irrelevant. The CR may not be apparent if `echo` is writing to the terminal, but it's there in the output of `echo`.

Comment: Yes, term, means terminal. Questioner just want to print, try my variant with bash + Linux. May be MacOs do it wrong.

Comment: Just because you don't see a character doesn't mean it's not there. Try `echo -e '\r-n' | od -tx1`. Compare with `printf %s -n | od -tx1`.

Comment: Hey, he just want to print. p.s. terminal: xterm.